# How to use webpack and css-loader to load only specific css class?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, stylesheet, css-loader

I'm using webpack, I have installed both `style-loader` and `css-loader`

*styles.css*

```
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
}

.foo {
    color:blue;
}

.bar {
    color:red;
}
```

*entry.js*

```
require('!style!css!./styles.css');

var css = require('!css!./styles.css');
console.log(css);
```

Using `require('!style!css!./styles.css')` results `<style>` into the page as below

[image]

Using `var css = require('!css!./styles.css')` then `console.log(css)` results as below

[image]

#### Question

Is it possible to load only specific css class e.g. `var fooClass = css.foo`, I intend to use this with my React components, e.g. `<input style={ foo }/>` or maybe `<input className={ foo }/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with `css-loader` and `style-loader` but you can use [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) to import a specific class into your react file.

It loads only the necessary css into the document and also it will create a unique name for your `class` at the time of loading. By this you can use same class name with different styles in different components!

Comment: I have seen `react-css-modules` while searching, how is it related to webpack, loader? plugin?, please explain a little bit more because I have read it but I didn't quite understand, thanks

Comment: `react-css-modules` is a better version of `css-loader`. It will be a query param to the existing `css-loader`. You can check here https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#webpack